# Change language code in URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am developing a website that works in two languages. I need to change URL to include the selected language.

What I exactly need is:

1. Pick the current URL
2. Check if the URL contains any language code
3. Append the code if not exist or change the code to the selected one if exists

For example, there is an URL for English (default):

```
http://localhost:11767/Home/resultMain?model=1&&type=1
```

When a user selects Spanish (es) it should be:

```
http://localhost:11767/es/Home/resultMain?model=1&&type=1
```

Comment: In which language is your backend written? Are you using node js?

Comment: @Daniel ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Change window.location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can parse the URL with the help of an a element then replace the part you want and re-build the URL :

```js
function addReplaceLangCode(url, langCode) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = document.getElementById('url').value; // or document.location.href;

  var paths = a.pathname.split('/');
  paths.shift();

  if(paths[0].length == 2) {
    paths[0] = langCode;
  }else{
    paths.unshift(langCode);
  }
  return a.protocol + '//' +
    a.host + '/' + paths.join('/') + 
    (a.search != '' ?  a.search : '') + 
    (a.hash != '' ?  a.hash : '');
}
    
function onClickReplace() {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = addReplaceLangCode( document.location.href, 'es');
}
```

```html
URL : <input type="text" id="url" style="width:400px" value="http://localhost:11767/Home/resultMain?model=1&&type=1"><input type="button" value="Replace" onclick="onClickReplace()"><br />
Result: <span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: this method will eliminate the part of query string parameters if the url is
http://localhost:11767/es/Home/resultMain?model=1&&type=1
and user click on english the link will be 
http://localhost:11767/en/Home/resultMain

Comment: Thanks very much it is now working fine and you really save my day :)

Comment: Littile bug in this code when the url is 
http://localhost:11767/en/Home/resultMain?model=2&type=2
and i click on en agin it will result
http://localhost:11767/en/Home/resultMain/?model=2&type=2
click again on en
http://localhost:11767/en/Home/resultMain//?model=2&type=2

Note the slash that is appended before question mark

Comment: Indeed. Please check now. We don't have to add extra '/' before the query string and the hash.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Still helpful today. I have replaced `'/'` with `(langCode == '' ? '' : '/')` to make it work the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is exactly this, what you want. But JavaScript can obtain URL using object "location". Especially `location.pathname` is useful for you. You can apply reg-exp on `location.pathname` to check if URL contain `/es/` and if yes, then translate website by proper Ajax requests to your backend.

But generally I recommending to use routing of your backend. The best solution in my opinion - use http headers to inform server about preferred language.

> https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Bulnet Vural's answer above, I wrote the following code because I needed to toggle the language path in and out of the url.

```
var getOtherLanguageLocation = function (currentUrl, languagePath) {
    // based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/42176588/1378980
    var anchorTag = document.createElement('a');
    anchorTag.href = currentUrl;
    var paths = anchorTag.pathname.split("/");

    // remove all the empty items so we don't get double slash when joining later.
    var paths = paths.filter(function (e) { return e !== '' })

    // the language will be at index 1 of the paths
    if (paths.length > 0 && paths[0].toLowerCase() == languagePath) {
        // remove the language prefix
        paths.splice(0, 1);
    } else {
        // add the language prefix
        paths.unshift(languagePath);
    }

    return anchorTag.protocol + '//' +
      anchorTag.host + '/' + paths.join('/') +
      anchorTag.search + anchorTag.hash;
};
```